# Продолжить выполнение функции после return

Tags: c#, unity3d, функции, return

Есть функция, которая возвращает значение, в другой класс. В середине функции, в зависимости от условия нужно вернуть значение и выполнить функцию до конца. Есть ли возможность вернуть это значение, без создания новой переменной?

```
public int count;
public example(){
    if(count<4){
        return count;
        //тут выполнение функции оборвется, хотя мне нужно что-бы она выполнилась дальше, ибо иначе она зациклится.
        count+=1;
    }
    else(){
        count = 1;
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Звучит как знатный костыль.  А в целом что надо сделать?

Comment: Делайте один `return` после if/else да и все. Если же у вас это некий "цикл", то посмотрите в сторону `yield return`. А так, ваш код очень странный, ибо вы возвращаете из метода то, что и так лежит внутри класса, в виде отдельной переменной. Какой смысл в возврате, если можно взять и сразу прочитать `count`? Вы уж определитесь, либо вы работаете с переменной, либо с данными, которые возвращает метод.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` + `yield return`, паттерн "итератор".

Comment: Интересно, что вы пытаетесь сделать

Answer (score 1):

Код:

```
public int count;
public int Example()
{
    if(count < 4)
    {
        count++;
        return count - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 1;
        return count;
    }
}
```